# EMI consideration for Microwave Sensor Module

Tags: sensor, emc, microwave, emi-filtering

I'm using Microwave Solutions MDU1720 [datasheet](https://www.microwave-solutions.com/media/wysiwyg/Datasheets/MDU1720.pdf) with recommendation that *The length of leads connecting the MDU to the signal processing circuitry must be minimised, to reduce pick up of electromagnetic interference. A maximum lead length of 1.5cm is recommended and screened leads are preferred.*  Due to other prototype constraints, however, I'm stuck with 15cm long 22gauge unshielded hookup wire for the +5V and GND leads.  Would it be likely enough to just twist these leads together and run perpendicularly away from the pcb?

[image: MDU1720]

Comment: The data sheet doesn't mention 1.5 cm.

Comment: Sorry, here it is https://www.microwave-solutions.com/applications/mechanical.html under Mechanical Considerations: Connections

Comment: Sorry, 1.5 cm is really too low for most applications and there's not much detail about the electrical interface either to make any sensible judgement.

Comment: Yeah, 1.5cm is too short for me to work with, but unless someone else chimes in, I suppose I'll at least change to foil shielded wire.  After that, any EMI that slips through hopefully won't hinder the MDU.  I also don't believe this matter will impact subsequent testing and recertification for FCC unintentional radiation.

Answer (score 1):

I guess 1.5cm is just a guideline so that customers do not come back to ask why it isn't working as expected. But 15cm for such sensors are really long. Ideally, we should have an amplifier as close to the IF as possible so that the desired IF signal is always larger than any impinging interferer. If you have a shielded coax, it would definitely work better.

Answer (score 0):

The interference in question is not from the 10 GHz RF, its the coupling of audio "buzz" from the environment into the amplifier, via the cables. You know how it sounds when you touch an audio line-in cable, but worse as the levels are lower. The signals of interest, a few hundred Hz, are similar frequency to the noise coupling from the mains.

But you can use a long cable. Dynamic microphones are (sometimes) passive devices producing mV level signals and they work ok with long cables. You need to obsess about managing the noise.

Most important if you're using unscreened cable will be to use a differential input to the amplifier. Noise will be almost all common mode if the cables are twisted. Twisting is better than nothing, but won't help much if you then ground one side and connect the other to a single-ended input.

I would say it would be easier to use good screened cable, than to use a differential input, but if that requirement is fixed then you need to do what you can to mitigate the noise that will be picked up.

Consider also having the first stage amplifiers on a board right behind the microwave module, then the noise pickup will be much less serious.